# Insect Eyes Vs Human Eyes?

Tags: optics, biology, vision

Humans have frontal eyes. Less field of view. But better resolving power.
Insects have lateral eyes. This means they have a large field of view. In some female insects the lateral eyes have much more space between them than the male counterparts, and therefore and even bigger field of view. But they have poor resolving power.

My questions :

1. Are resolving power and field of view correlated?  That is higher the resolving power, poorer the depth of field. It doesn't make sense from a Physics point of view. Maybe it's just a trade-off for conserving energy in living organisms. You can only have one?
2. This question is for the physicists who like to dabble in evolutionary biology as well. What is the advantage of frontal eyes over lateral eyes from an evolutionary perspective? Does having lesser field of view makes us better hunters?

Comment: Question 2 seems off-topic here, as it's about biology and not physics.

Comment: to me, your q2 is off-topic, though q1 may be a reasonable question about optics.

Comment: About the second question, I always though that when chasing prey having frontal eyes is better, unless you are walking sideways. 360º would be better anyway.

Comment: To add to @jinawee for question 2: You will usually see eyes on the side of the head on prey animals (antelopes, hares, rabbits) and frontal eyes on predators (tigers, lions, leopards, and... humans). I am pretty sure it is an evolutionary treat for predators to be able to focus on the view straight ahead while hunting and for prey to be able to see as much as possible around them to detect movements from danger and maybe a predator sneaking in. There would be no need for a predator to have 360 degree view, so the evolutionary focus was on the frontal view.